# Invalid Geometry - Which column can I change to geometry?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a csv file with thes two columns (amongst others): `localisation` and `geo_point_2d`.

Here is the content of one cell of `localisation` :

```
{"type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [[[[-53.5441768169403, 5.50647948448245], [-53.5467839241028, 5.50461059944752], [-53.5478729009628, 5.5055717410565], [-53.5473901033401, 5.50614308560981], [-53.5477602481842, 5.50646346549284], [-53.5460811853409, 5.50824691035157], [-53.5441768169403, 5.50647948448245]]]]}
```

Here is the content of the cell on the same line as the previous one in the column 'geo_point_2d':

```
5.50638356893;-53.5461903708
```

I migrated the table to postgis and tried to change the types of these columns to `geometry` with :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name
ALTER COLUMN localisation TYPE geometry
```

For the column `geo_point_2d` I get :

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "5.50638356893;" <-- parse error at position 14 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

I tried to change the `;` by `,` but the error was still there.

For the column `localisation` I get :

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "{"" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

In the best case I would like to access to polygons instead of points. When getting the csv file a GeoJson files is also available but I needed to make some changes in the document before visualizing it. The GeoJson displays well on QGis.
I guess I am under `ESPG:4326`

My question is : How can I get to change the type of the columns to geometry ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to tell PostGIS how to coerce the `TEXT` values into `GEOMETRY`s; the implicit type cast is able to cast *WKT/WKB* between `TEXT` and `GEOMETRY` (while you provide either *GeoJSON* or...well, two numbers as `TEXT`).

Run

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ALTER COLUMN localisation TYPE GEOMETRY(MULTIPOLYGON, <SRID>)
    USING ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(localisation)
;
```

**Udate:**

If your geometries are of different type, either use the generic `GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY, 4326)`, or, in this case, force to `ST_Multi`:

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
   ALTER COLUMN localisation TYPE GEOMETRY(MULTIPOLYGON, <SRID>)
     USING ST_SetSRID(ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(localisation)), 4326)
 ;
```

The expression after `USING` will be applied to the column value; you can do arbitrary things here as long as they return the correct column type as specified.

Comment: I changed the SRID to `4326` and got : `ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)`, with the sird set to `0` I get : `ERROR:  Geometry type (Polygon) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)`, then I changed `MULTIPOLYGON` to `POLYGON` and got : `eometry type (MultiPolygon) does not match column type (Polygon)`

Comment: ST_SETSRID and ST_MULTI will solve that

Comment: As @IanTurton says; it's strange though since `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` is supposed to default to EPSG:4326, as it's the GeoJSON standard. I can't pinpoint exactly where, but I experienced some typemod errors where they should not be with the current PG version. May need to investigate....

Comment: @Basile any progress? Did this help?